# Webpack4+Gulp4 не переводит ES6/babel в js (и не импортирует), а копирует

Tags: javascript, babel, webpack4, gulp4

С переводом на последние версии перестал переводиться ES6/babel в js. Есть основной .js файл, который включает все остальные и в итоге должен быть образован один файл из многих. Но `import '../js/header/header.js';` так и остается в итоговом коде в dist. В чем проблема?

В .babelrc

```
"presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
],
"plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
]
```

webpack.conf.js

```
export default function makeWebpackConfig({
    watch = true,
    sourcemaps = false,
    inspect = false,
    notify = false,
    eslint = true
}) {
    return {
        entry: path.resolve('./app/scripts/app'),
        watch,
        inspect,
        bail: false,
        profile: true,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('./dist/scripts/'),
            filename: 'app.min.js',
            pathinfo: false,
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules'],
            extensions: ['.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'happypack/loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
            ].filter(loader => loader)
        },
        plugins: [
            new HappyPack({
                loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                threads: 4,
                verbose: false,
                cache: true
            })
```

задача scripts

```
function runWebpack(watch = false) {
    return function (callback) {
        const webpackConfig = makeWebpackConfig({
            watch,
            inspect: isDebug,
            sourcemaps: isDebug,
            notify: NOTIFY
        });
        return webpack(webpackConfig, (error, stats) => {
            const jsonStats = stats.toJson();
            if (jsonStats.errors.length) {
                jsonStats.errors.forEach(message => {
                    scriptsErrorHandler.call({emit() {}}, {message});
                }); }
            if (watch === false) callback();
        }); };}
gulp.task('scripts', runWebpack(false));
gulp.task('scripts:watch', runWebpack(true));
```

Вызываю в gulpfile.babel.js

```
function watching(done) {
    global.watch = true; 
    gulp.watch('app/+(blocks|styles)/**/*.+(styl|less)', gulp.series(styles, reload));
    gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', gulp.series('scripts:watch'));
    //gulp.start('scripts:watch'); // не работает в 4 версии...
};
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(styles, gulp.parallel('scripts', 'browser-sync', watching)));
```

Comment: В мире JS  - обновления доставляют часто нестерпимую боль :)